# How to fix Ocaml Unbound constructor error?

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec natadd_nat c =
    match c with
    | 0 -> O
    | _ -> (S (natadd_nat (c-1))) 

let rec natadd_int c =
    match c with
    | O -> 0
    | S n' -> 1+(natadd_int n')

let natadd a b =
    natadd_nat((natadd_int a) + (natadd_int b))
```

This is the code I wrote in ocaml. natadd_nat is a function that converts an int to a symbol consisting of O and S. natadd_int is a function that converts the symbols of O and S into int. The natadd function changes the symbols a and b from natadd_int to int. And after adding the two values ​​changed to int, put it in the natadd_nat function and change it back to a symbol.

But in the natadd_nat function,

> Unbound constructor O

error occurred in the

```
| 0 -> O
```

part.

How can I solve this?

example)

```
# let two = S (S O) ;;
# let three = S (S (S O)) ;;
# natadd two three ;;
- : nat = S (S (S (S (S O))))
```

Comment: If this is a complete example, you're missing a type definition that defines the constructor `O` and `S`. If it's not a complete example, please see how to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type constructor requires a type be declared with that constructors (or in this case *constructors*.

Judging from the code you've posted, you're likely missing something like:

```
type nat = O | S of nat
```

Comment: thank you! I solved the problem. But an error occurs when calling the function. When I call the natadd function, 'Unbound value natadd' error occurs. How can I solve this?